# Algorithm - the time complexity of deletion in a unsorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

Suppose there is a unsorted array A, and it contains an element x (x is the pointer of the element), and every element has a satellite variable k. So, we can get the following time complexity (for worst cases):

If we want to **Search** for a particular K, then it costs O(n).

if we want to **Insert** an element, then it costs O(1), because A just adds the element to the end.

What if we know x, then **Delete** it from the array A?

We have to *Search* for x.k first and get the index of x, then *Delete* x via its index in A, right?

So for **Delete**, it costs O(n) too, right?

thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Finding the element with a given value is linear.

Since the array isn't sorted anyway, you can do the deletion itself in constant time. First swap the element you want to delete to the end of the array, then reduce the array size by one element.

Comment: That's pretty cool. You couldn't implement a general purpose delete like that though because even though the array is not sorted, it still might have some particular order to it that needs to be preserved.

Comment: @Dangph: That would still be sorted -- just not in ascending (or descending) order.

Comment: @Jerry: I think authors normally distinguish between "ordered" and "sorted". A "sorted" array is specifically one in which the order depends on the values of the objects in it. An array that is ordered by insert-time is not normally described as "sorted" even when it is important that the insert-time order is preserved.

Comment: That said, the questioner calls the array "unsorted" without further comment, so I think it's fair to assume that the order is unimportant until proved otherwise.

Comment: @JerryCoffin is this how it is normally implemented? that is, to swap element in unsorted arr to end and reduce?

Comment: @ish2f4f: In most typical cases (e.g., a C++ `vector` or a Java `ArrayList`) deleting an element in the middle of the collection can't change the order of remaining elements, so they have to move all the other elements to cover up the hole, so to speak.

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks, so in that case, the deletion is O(n).

Comment: @ish2f4f: Correct.

Comment: @JerryCoffin just to be clear, finding the element with a given index value is constant (hence arrays being random access), but finding the element of a given value is linear since you have to inspect (worst-case) every element in the array?

Comment: @YuChen: Yes, searching an unsorted array normally requires a linear search.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's right. Also, if it's an array, deleting alone will take `O(n)` time because after you delete the element, you'll need to shift all the elements to the right of that element one place to the left. So, even if you know x (for example, you will only delete the first element), it will take `O(n)` time.

Answer (score 1):

Worst case time complexity for deletion operation in  a sorted array is **O(n)**,
If the array is not sorted and it is mentioned that after deletion operation
order of the array shouldn't be altered then time complexity will be same as **O(n)**
otherwise it will be **O(1)**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It takes `O(n)` time to find the element you want to delete. Then in order to delete it, you must shift all elements to the right of it one space to the left. This is also `O(n)` so the total complexity is linear.

Also, if you're talking about statically allocated arrays, insert takes `O(n)` as well. You have to resize the array in order to accommodate the extra element. There are ways to amortize this running time to `O(1)` though.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to shift anything since the array is unsorted, you can just fill the gap by using the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Unsorted Array

Ex:

```
Items Value     [3,   5,  1,  7,  4]
Items Address   [&1, &2, &3, &4, &5]
Deleting - Value 5
```

**1. Deletion - Order to be preserved** - O(n + n) - **O(2n)** ~> O(n)

i)   O(n) - Finding the position of that element (Index = 1 for value 5)

ii)  O(n) - After deleting that element, the rest of the items (1, 7, 4) needs to be reshuffled to hold the previous item's address. Like

```
Items Value     [3,   1,  7,  4]
Items Address   [&1, &2, &3, &4]
```

**2. Deletion - Without preserving the Order** - O(n + 1 + 1) - **O(2 + n)** ~> O(n)

i)   O(n) - Finding the position of that element (Index = 1 for value 5)

ii)  O(1) - Swape with the last element of the array.

```
Items Value     [3,   4,  1,  7,  5]
Items Address   [&1, &2, &3, &4, &5]
```

iii) O(1) - Delete the last element of the array.

```
Items Value     [3,   4,  1,  7]
Items Address   [&1, &2, &3, &4]
```